# Array arguments countifs are of different size - Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've seen another post about this already but it wont fix my issue. For a research I easily want to create an overview of the data with Google Sheets. At this moment I get a #VALUE error when I use a `COUNTIFS` function.

[Link to spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/157T-HulQ9REw3jh1fL2O1SfatXg8MgIJrq3cdkA9ZQk/edit?usp=sharing)

In sheet1 (Data) you can find the research data.
In sheet2 (Overview) I want to make the overview of the data.
In this case every row is the data of one respondent.
They were able to cross multiple answers at a question about the type of holidays they took in the last two years.
In column `G:K` the answers can be found.

I want to create an overview where I can see how many times people from different ages answered a specific question.

I use the formula:

```
=COUNTIFS(Data!$D$2:$D$7, $A2, Data!$I$2:$N, B$1)
```

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Hope that anyone is able to help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In B2 of the second tab try

```
=countif(ArrayFormula(flatten(Data!$B$2:$B$6&Data!$G$2:$K$6)), Overview!$A2&Overview!B$1)
```

and fill down and to the right.

See if that works?